# Syntax error when using .apply() on DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have been working on this thing for a bit now; still stuck.  I am trying to figure out how to run some logic statements and insert the results into a field in a dataframe.  I Googled for a solution and came up with this basic concept: `

```
df['new column name'] = df['column name'].apply(lambda x: 'value if condition is met' if x condition else 'value if condition is not met')`
```

So I tried to apply that to my specific scenario and came up with this.

```
import nltk
nltk.download('vader_lexicon')
nltk.download('punkt')

# first, we import the relevant modules from the NLTK library
from nltk.sentiment.vader import SentimentIntensityAnalyzer

# next, we initialize VADER so we can use it within our Python script
sid = SentimentIntensityAnalyzer()

# the variable 'message_text' now contains the text we will analyze.
#message_text = '''Like you, I am getting very frustrated with this process. I am genuinely trying to be as reasonable as possible. I am not trying to "hold up" the deal at the last minute. I'm afraid that I am being asked to take a fairly large leap of faith after this company (I don't mean the two of you -- I mean Enron) has screwed me and the people who work for me.'''
message_text = df['body'].tolist()

#message_text = str(message_text)
for message in message_text:
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['sentiment'])
    scores = sid.polarity_scores(message)
    for key in sorted(scores):
        df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: 'positive' if scores["compound"]] >= 0.05 'negative' if scores["compound"]] <= -0.05 else 'neutral')
```

When I run the code, I get this error:

```
  File "<ipython-input-82-310bd1405427>", line 20
    df['sentiment'].apply(lambda x: 'positive' if scores["compound"]] >= 0.05 'negative' if scores["compound"]] <= -0.05 else 'neutral')
                                                                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I know the problem is with the last line of code.  I just don't know how to fix it.  Any thoughts, anyone?

Comment: shoulnd't `scores["compound"]]` be `scores["compound"]` with one less bracket?

Comment: also in the if statement you are not using the `sentiment` value anywhere, why use `apply` then ?

Comment: Come on now. I cant see how you could do due diligence and miss that typo before posting. Beyond that, you can use `np.where` and fill na's at the end or use `np.select`

Comment: This seems overly convoluted if all you need is to apply a function to a column. In any case, the issue is just a trivial typo. As @roganjosh said, low effort.